# Búsqueda de datos por fecha

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una página que muestra un historial de transacciones por fecha, yo pongo una fecha de inicio y una fecha hasta para poder buscar, funciona bien todo, pero si trato de buscar los registros de la fecha actual, por ejemplo desde:2019/07/25 hasta 2019/07/25 no me bota ningún resultado, mi consulta esta hecha con between.

En cambio si le pongo desde: 2019/07/25 hasta un día después que aun no pasa, entonces si me bota los resultados actuales de hoy.

```php
$consulta="select * from $tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$desde1' AND '$hasta1'";
```

Aumentándole +1 a $hasta1 no funciona. También lo había hecho con

```
" where fecha >= .. and fecha<= .."
```

Tal vez me puedan ayudar a que si pueda buscar el mismo día actual "hoy"

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que estás consultando la misma fecha y, sin que le pases la hora, también te consulta a la misma hora, entonces si los datos no tienen esa hora/minutos/segundos exactos no te los va a devolver porque no coincide.

Puedes solucionar el problema añadiendo un dia a la segunda fecha o poniendo las horas correctamente:

```
$consulta="select * from $tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$desde1' AND DATE_ADD('$hasta1', INTERVAL +1 DAY)";
```

---

```
date_modify($hasta1, '+1 day');

$consulta="select * from $tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$desde1' AND '$hasta1'";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @AlexanderMorales recuerda marcar la respuesta que te haya servido para poder ayudar a otros usuarios con el mismo problema!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más fácil es que cambies la query en función de las fechas algo de este estilo:

```
if ($desde1 == $hasta1) {
    $consulta = "select * from $tabla WHERE fecha = '$desde1'";
} else {
    $consulta = "select * from $tabla WHERE fecha >= '$desde1' AND fecha <= '$hasta1'";
}
```

También te advierto que tengas cuidado, si eso son valores traidos directamente desde cliente porque tendrías un problema de SQLInjection.